# Synonym for "compelling"/"inviting" starting with R

Tags: single-word-requests

I originally wrote

> I think one of the most compelling parts of being an engineer is the
>   holistic nature of the job

in my essay, but thought of a better word later to replace "comeplling". For some reason, I can't remember the word. What I can remember is that it starts with an "r" (possibly "re") and means something along the lines of "compelling" or "inviting". I know it wasn't the word "riveting".

Comment: Maybe *Rewarding*?

Comment: "Irresistible" _almost_ starts with "re".

Comment: though riveting would be very apposite...

Comment: Aren't downvoters supposed to explain?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Rewarding" seems to fit as do "intriguing" and "interesting."

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: This might've been it, and works fine in my sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible words are **intriguing** and **alluring**:

> **in·trigu·ing** (adj)
> Arousing one's curiosity or interest; fascinating. ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intriguing))
>
> **al·lur·ing** (adj)
> Powerfully and mysteriously attractive or fascinating; seductive. ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alluring))

None of these words start with a "r", but they at least have a "r" in middle :)